# Javascript reduce taking too much time to convert array into object

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have 2 lists of array. One having 50 elements(`users`) and other with 20000 elements(`allUsers`). I have to filter `users` based on if they are present in `allUsers`.

For that, i am converting `allUsers` into object and using that object to filter out `users`.

`allUsers` is an array of object with 3 keys.

So, creating object from array is taking too much of time. How can i reduce the time of the overall operationn?

```
  const usersMap = allUsers.reduce((aa, user) => {
    acc = { ...aa, [user.id]: user }
    return aa
  }, {})

  const matchedUsers = users.reduce((aa, user) => {
    const mappedUser = usersMap[user.id]
    if (mappedUser) {
      aa.push(mappedUser)
    }
    return aa
  }, [])
```

Comment: Your use of spread is definitlely going to slow this down. `{ ...aa, [user.id]: user }` creates a new object every iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of spread is definitlely going to slow this down. `{ ...aa, [user.id]: user }` creates a new object every iteration rather than just adding a new property to it, and in so doing has to iterate every property of the spread object again making your reduce approach O(n^2) rather than being O(n).

You can start by making your reduce more efficient by removing the unnecessary spread and simply assigning a new property in the accumulator.

```
const usersMap = allUsers.reduce((aa, user) => {
    aa[user.id] = user;
    return aa;
}, {});
```

Or you can try using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
const usersMap = new Map(allUsers.map((user) => [user.id, user]));

const matchedUsers = users.reduce((aa, user) => {
  if (usersMap.has(user.id)) {
    aa.push(usersMap.get(user.id));
  }
  return aa;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const lookup = new Set(users.map(x => x.id));
const matchedUsers = allUsers.filter(x => lookup.has(x.id));
```

Instead of

1. Building a map of 20k items
2. Go through 50 items trying to relate them back to the map
3. Return an array of all the map values that match

Flip the operation around and

1. Get a set of 50 IDs to match.
2. Extract the up to 50 items from `allUsers` that have a matching ID.

Since there is no object created from the 20k items, this reduces the time to create one to zero.

Comment: *'this reduces the time to create one to zero'*, it is still O(n) on each array for time complexity, but I agree it reduces space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
users.filter(user => allUsers.find(u => u.id === user.id))
```

Filter the users that aren't found in all the users.